# How to use CSG with VTK in python?

Tags: python, vtk, csg

I want to use CSG with VTK in python to perform substractions.
I already have VTK installed.

For the CSG I was thinking to install: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycsg .

How would I go around using it for custom PolyDatas in order to substract one object from another? I don't mind if it's a bit slow or I have to export data to a `.STL` file.

I am already aware of the `vtkBooleanOperationPolyDataFilter`, but it is simply not good enough for what I need, so maybe CSG will do the subtractions better.

Comment: 1) If you ask a question, it should be a question and not a ... tag cloud. 2) Questions end with a "?".

Comment: Could you describe what is the issue with the `vtkBooleanOperationPolyDataFilter`? What are its shortcomings compared to pycsg?